# How can I flatten HashMaps and get only a list of keys in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, flatmap

I need to get only a list of keys from a hash map.

Here is how I do it:

data is hashmap type.

```
val flatten = data.flatMap { it.entries }
val keys = flatten.map { it.key }
```

As you can see on the rows above first, the data is flattened, and then with help of the map method I create a list only of keys.
But it looks like that `flatten.map { it.key }` work slow.

My question is, is there any other way to fetch a list of keys from Hashmap, or how can I improve the performance of the code above?

Comment: `data` is a Map with values that are Maps, and you want a list of all keys of all those inner maps? Is `data.flatMap { it.keys }` what you’re looking for?

Comment: What is *actually* the type of `data`? The actual name of the type, please, not "hashmap type".

Comment: @Tenfour04 thanks, yes this is what I looked for! if you will create an answer I will accept it.